# What’s the diﬀer­ence be­tween “to re­duce ʙʏ one-third” and “to re­duce ɪɴᴛᴏ one-third”?

Tags: numbers

> A sam­ple of fluo­rine gas oc­cu­pies a vol­ume of 600 mL at 760 torr.
> Given that the tem­per­a­ture re­mains the same, cal­cu­late
> the pres­sure re­quired to **re­duce its vol­ume by one-third**.

I don't need an an­swer. I just want to know what op­er­a­tion the
ques­tion is re­fer­ring to.

What con­fuses me is the part at the end of the ques­tion: does *re­duce its
vol­ume by one-third* re­fer to re­duc­ing the vol­ume by one-third? Like you
sub­tract one-third of 600 into 600?

Or does it re­fer to re­duc­ing the vol­ume of 600 into one-third
meaning that 600 should be di­vided by three?

Comment: You must focus on the little word "by" to tell you what to do. First you calculate 1/3 as you expected, Subtract that amount from 600, to "reduce its volume **by**" 200. Then figure the pressure you need to produce 400.

Comment: ...and "reduce *into* 1/3" would be to a volume of 200 (much greater pressure).

Comment: To reduce a volume _by_ 1/3 is to end up with a volume 2/3 of the original, to reduce a volume to 1/3 means to reduce _by_ 2/3 leaving a volume of 1/3. In more mathematecal language if V is the original volume then reducing V _by_ y/x is to end up with a volume of V-yV/x. I'm actualy more confused by the term "reduce into 1/3" which mixes two mathematical terms to me.

Comment: Similarly, when you buy something at a 10% discount, you end up paying 90% of the original price **by** subtracting. You do not buy it for 10% of the original price.

Comment: @WeatherVane Please consider my point about units and pure numbers in my answer. To reduce into 1/3 is almost meaningless and does not mean to reduce into 1/3 ml.

Comment: @Anton I don't think OP or anyone else has suggested that it means either 1/3 ml or 599.666 ml. In fact OP asks if the 1/3 of 600 ml is to be taken off, or is the result.

Comment: @WeatherVane Indeed. I think I have strayed into a possible ambiguity that has not really been mentioned by anyone else so far. I included the point about units because they are an essential part of definition of quantities and their significance is too often forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

***by*** is a very versatile preposition. Most comments so far could easily have been made into answers, so I claim no greater authority in setting out this understanding:

> by: Preposition
>
> If something increases or decreases by a particular amount, that amount is gained or lost.
>
> "Violent crime has increased by 10 percent since last year."
>
> "Their pay has been cut by one-third."
>
> [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/by)

A reduction by one third is a decrease of one third: so 600 ml is to be decreased ***by*** 600/3 ml (= 200 ml) to a final volume of 400 ml.

As commented by others, a reduction ***into*** one third would be a reduction to 600/3 ml (= 200 ml).

I draw your attention to the careful exclusion of ambiguity by the formulation of the question. The volume is expressed in units of ml. The reduction is expressed only as a number (1/3); it has no units. There is therefore no reason to interpret the question as meaning a reduction of 600 ml by 1/3 ml to 599.666... ml. Nor may we imagine that the 600 ml is to be compressed to 1/3 ml.